# Скидки по статусам пользователей

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!
Задача - сделать для пользователей статус (золотой, серебряный или бронзовый) и давать скидку в зависимости от статуса.
Статус я сделал просто дополнительным полем у пользователя - назначаю руками.

А как теперь скидку давать? В админке на вкладке "Магазин" порылся в разделе "Скидки" -> "Работа с корзиной", но ничего подходящего не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай 3 группы пользователей: http://joxi.ru/OzkLVP3JTJAFNYx51pE

А потом 3 скидки для разных групп:

http://joxi.ru/9zgLVIwyTJDoAlWvBdw

http://joxi.ru/ITkLVIwyTJDJAme2QCw

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось!